# How to animation to all path of SVG

Tags: animation, svg, svg-animate

I want to animate to a SVG and delay to any elements.
Please see this [link](https://trionndesign.com/) and lion SVG.
The animation of this is simple but to delay to any path is very Time consuming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is pretty simple to recreate this effect.

I didn't check to see how that site did it, but this is how I would do it.

Firstly we need an SVG where all the paths are in a group (`<g>`);

```
<svg>
  <g id="anim">
    <!-- path elements in here -->
  </g>
</svg>
```

On page load, we set a transform on the group that moves it (an all the paths) off the side of the SVG.

```
group.setAttribute("transform", "translate(-100, 0)");
```

Then, for the animation, we loop through all the `<path>` elements one by one (with a delay) adding a class that uses a `transform` to move the paths back on screen.

```
.onto-screen-anim
{
  transition: transform 1s ease-out;
  transform: translateX(100px);  /* 100 = width of viewBox */
}
```

The transition causes the path to slide in smoothly.

---

**Working demo**

```js
var group = document.getElementById("anim");


// Generate a lot of test paths in our SVG.
// This is just for the demo as an alternative to having a big SVG in our snippet.
for (var i=0; i<100; i++) {
  path = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "path");
  var r1 = 5 + Math.random() * 45;
  var r2 = 5 + Math.random() * 45;
  var a1 = Math.random() * 2 * Math.PI;
  var a2 = a1 + (Math.random() - 0.5);
  path.setAttribute("d", [
    'M', 50 + Math.cos(a1) * r1, 50 + Math.sin(a1) * r1,
    'L', 50 + Math.cos(a2) * r2, 50 + Math.sin(a2) * r2,
  ].join(' '));
  group.appendChild(path);
}


// Add a transform to the<svg> root element to move all the child
// elements off the left edge of the SVG where we want them to start.
// The value 100 represents the width of the viewBox.
group.setAttribute("transform", "translate(-100, 0)");


// For our animation, just loop through all paths, adding the 
// "onto-screen-anim" class that moves them back into view.

var INTER_PATH_DELAY = 16;   // 10 milliseconds

var allPaths = group.querySelectorAll("path");
var itemNum = 0;
function startOnePathMoving() {
  // Add the class that moves the path onto screen
  allPaths[itemNum++].classList.add("onto-screen-anim");
  // if there are paths left, then call this function again
  // after a short delay to start the next one moving
  if (itemNum < allPaths.length)
    setTimeout(startOnePathMoving, INTER_PATH_DELAY);
}

// Start the first timeout to get the animation started
setTimeout(startOnePathMoving, INTER_PATH_DELAY);
```

```css
/* Make sure the paths that are off the SVG can't be seen */
svg {
  overflow: hidden;
}

/* The class that moves the paths back onto screen */
.onto-screen-anim
{
  transition: transform 1s ease-out;
  transform: translateX(100px);  /* 100 = width of viewBox */
}

/* Styling for our demo paths. You can ignore this for a real SVG */
path {
  fill: none;
  stroke: grey;
  stroke-width: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<svg width="400" height="400" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
  <g id="anim"></g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks men. i put your javascript code but Error gives: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null

Comment: Probably because your SVG doesn't have a `<g>` with id `"anim"`.  What I have put here is a demo.  You'll need to adapt it to your situation.

Comment: Where is your SVG?  Does that lion image belong to you? I am not going to help you steal someone elses graphics for your own site.

Comment: No,
I use of that SVG because That is easy to learn and that have many path tag, I just want to learn this method. If i going to steal that i use another SVG !!!
Anyway if you don't want to help, no problem. Thanks for all your help :)

Comment: Ok. Note that it is supposed to be `id="anim"` not `id="anime"`. You need to remove `style="transform: ...;"` from the SVG because `style` attributes over-ride CSS.  Also, the `id="anim"` is supposed to be added to the top group, not all groups.  Start with those fixes and you should be closer to having it work.

Comment: Thanks men, I do your notes later and I say the result. :)

Comment: I'm studying how to animate svg and this is helpful.  I setup a copy at https://codepen.io/pixeldroid/pen/ELbemo.  I'm not able to figure out how to prevent the svg from appearing before the animation.  Can you see the problem? Thanks much.

Comment: @Mitch The reason you already have an SVG on screen is because your initial SVG already has all the paths.  Get rid of them. https://codepen.io/PaulLeBeau/pen/xjpEVX

Comment: Got it.  Thanks much for taking the time to answer.